# Angular 2 Nested ngFor Not Woring

Tags: angular, angular2-template

The above mentioned code not working it shows the error in my console

```
<ul *ngFor="let value of Course.module" class="list-unstyled lesson-order-wrapper" ><!--[dragula]="zero-bag" -->
    <li class="lesson-container closed" id='less{{value.id}}'> 
        <div class="lesson-headding " (click)="slideUpnDown(value.id)">{{value.module_name}} <span class="icon-down-arrow pull-right panel-icon"></span></div>
        <div class="sub-lessons"  >
            <ul class="list-unstyled" *ngFor="let val of Course.OrderView[value.id]" [dragula]="value.module_name" id="1">
                <li class="lesson-titles">{{val.quiz_title}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Error:

> AdminCourseOrderComponent.html:24 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ
>   supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only
>   supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: what is not working what is the error

Comment: Course.OrderView[value.id] must be array i think in your response it's object

Comment: furthermore, I suppose that you want to write *ngFor let val of value. If you're concatenate two forms, is because you want the inner for is referred to the first